# Jboss EAP 6.4.6 add basic auth for all application

Tags: java, authentication, configuration, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a running Jboss EAP and some applications on it deployed.
Problemm is that i have task to make a authentification for apps bu i can't change them !

I've googled a lot of resoucess, but all of them describes the ways with app modifications (jboss-web.xml, web.xml etc.) that not suits for me.

Does there any kind of config to attemp this ? without app modifications ?
for example: require login/pass for any request for app, or for only one defined ?

Comment: Not without app modifications.  Your should revise your requirements.

Comment: Place the JBoss behind an HTTP proxy (eg. Apache) and implement authentication in the reverse proxy